# How can I use autolayout to get a view's height to be the same as the height of the largest label?

Tags: swift, autolayout, constraints

I have two labels next to each other in a `UIView`, and I'd like the `UIView` to adopt the height of the highest `UILabel`. If I pin them both to the top and bottom, I've just overconstrained the whole thing. And priorities don't seem to work for me either, since I won't know for certain which `UILabel` should "win". Is there an elegant way to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use inequality constraints. If they are aligned at the top, you can just set the container's top to equal the label tops. Then, you set the bottom to be greater than label1's bottom and, with another constraint, greater than label2's bottom. That leaves ambiguity because it can be *any* height that's greater than both. So, you can set a quite-low priority constraint to make the view 0 height, which resolves the ambiguity.

If the tops are not aligned, then you can use inequalities there, too. Container top <= label1 top and container top <= label2 top. The low-priority 0-height constraint will cause the container to hug the two labels.